# What is the standard algorithm for converting unicode characters into lowercase?

Tags: string, unicode, lowercase, uppercase

I want to know the standard algorithm for converting unicode characters into lowercase as proposed by [unicode.org](http://unicode.org/).

Also, do most programming languages follow this proposed standard?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I want to know the standard algorithm
>   for converting unicode characters into
>   lowercase as proposed by unicode.org.

The basic algorithm is simply to concatenate the lowercase of each individual character (as defined by the penultimate column in [UnicodeData.txt](http://unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt)).  There are also some [special rules](http://unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/SpecialCasing.txt) to handle multiple-character mappings (İ → i̇ with an extra COMBINING DOT ABOVE the i), conditional mappings (Σ → ς at the end of a word, but σ otherwise), and language-sensitive rules (like Turkish dotless ı).

> Also, do most programming languages
>   follow this proposed standard?

Java does.  Python implements the basic rules, but not the special rules.  And C has no standardized Unicode support at all.

Comment: How about javascript? Does it follow the standard?

Comment: JavaScript implements the basic casing rules, but not the special ones.

Answer (score 2):

.NET does have unicode support and offers built-in functions to switch between upper and lower case.   This is probably true with some other languages, as well.

Comment: .NET is a platform, not a language. Win32 has unicode support as well.

Comment: But it applies to all languages using the .NET Framework, including C#, VB.NET, F#, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Programming languages vary in how well they support unicode. Most do not have unicode characters as a built-in type. Typically it is either handled in a library, or by OS calls.

For instance, C++ doesn't have a native unicode character type, but does have locale support in the stl (which is defined as part of the language). Ada does have a native type Wide_Character, as well as library support for manipulating it.

Comment: "most do not have unicode characters as built-in type": that's no longer true for more modern languages.

Comment: Perhaps, but many of those "older" languages (eg: The C family) are still in immensely heavy use. A lot of those "more modern languages" get more press than use. Still, they are available if native unicode support is important to you.

Comment: Even "modern" languages like Java and C# don't actually have a Unicode character type; `char` means a UTF-16 code unit, which could be only half of a character.